# Features in Java which are absent in scala

Tags: java, scala

Both Java and Scala are OO programing language (Scala is functional as well). I am new to Scala and as per my understanding, Scala is an improvement over Java (as far as OOP is concerned). What are the features/functionalities that is there in Java, but have not been introduced in Scala? Following are the few which I am aware of :

1. Scala does not have static. Instead of that it has objects.
2. Scala does not have the concept of "checked exception".
3. Primitives are not there in Scala.

Comment: I smell a flamebait :)

Comment: @Ashalynd, :-). Scala is something which I have started learning recently. But, much before that, I have gone through numerous discussions which talked about static and checked exception (#1 and #2 in my question) and why they are bad. :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  a list of language differences

Comment: @DaveNewton, My intention is to understand the features that should not be there in an ideal OOP (Learn from mistakes). Incidentally, Java and Scala are the OOP languages I am familiar with.

Comment: What's "ideal", and who defines it? That's opinion, also a reason to close. Learn Smalltalk.

Comment: @ArnabBiswas then you won't be lucky, because Scala is explicitly designed to have good Java interop. If you were ok to drop that, I am sure a lot of features would be missing, e.g. method overloading, perhaps abstract classes (as opposed to traits), broken array variance, ...

Comment: Primitives certainly are "there" in Scala. The boxing and unboxing are far more seamless than in Java, which can be good or bad, depending on your perspective. Any parameterized / generic type's type parameters may be specialized for particular primitives to eliminate the boxing and unboxing costs when the type parameter is instantiated to those particular primitive types.

Comment: What constitutes a "feature?" … Wait, don't answer that…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether something is a "feature" is of course debatable. You could as well say, Scala has the feature that exceptions are not checked and thus not PITA... Same with unified types and primitives (which Scala still has for performance reasons under the hood).

Otherwise, the following come to my mind

- Enums. not a language construct in Scala
- for-loops in the Java sense, no `break` and `continue` (only via ordinary methods); and consequently no jump-to labels
- you can have multiple independent constructors in Java classes (I think), whereas in Scala each secondary constructor must call into a primary constructor (correct?)
- definition and assignment of a variable separated (`final int x; ...; x = 3`)
- `assert` not a language construct
- method arguments act as mutable variables in Java, in Scala they are read-only vals.
- related to the absense of `static` in favour of singleton `object`s: no static inner classes
- no special ternary operator `?`; in Scala you use `if` which is an expression
- no array literals, although I guess `Array(1, 2, 3)` could be optimised in a future Scala compiler version.
- `switch` and pattern matching work differently. `switch` allows fall through cases, but only works on few types.
- a few more primitive operators, e.g. pre-/post increment `++i`, `i++`

Most other things are *different* views on things (e.g. declaration site versus call site variance), but not really features that only exist in Java.